# Azure Function error Unable to load DLL

Tags: c#, azure-functions, html-to-pdf

## Problem

I am trying to create a azure function to create html to pdf. It runs locally perfectly fine but  when I deployed it to azure function It shoes me the error

## Error

> Unable to load DLL 'libwkhtmltox' or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found.

## Code

```
public static HttpResponseMessage Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function,"post", Route = null)]HttpRequest req, TraceWriter log)
    {
        log.Info("C# HTTP trigger HtmlToPdf processed a request.");

        //string name = req.Query["name"];

        string requestBody = new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEnd();
        dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Body>(requestBody);

        var pdf = Pdf
            .From(data.Html)
            .Content();

        log.Info($"PDF Generated. Length={pdf.Length}");

        var res = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        res.Content = new ByteArrayContent(pdf);
        res.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
        res.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("inline");
        return res;
    }
```

Comment: Hmmm....perhaps it could not load DLL 'libwkhtmltox' or one of its dependencies?  Did you upload it(them)?  Classic case of _it works on my machine_?

Comment: Yes how I can able to resolve it?

Comment: Please provide some more details. This is very little to go on with

Comment: Which pdf convert package do you use? And what's your function version, v1 or v2?

Comment: azure function v2, open htmltopdf

Comment: How do you define `Body` in `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Body>(requestBody)`? I use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody)` and `(string)data.Html` to convert json request body. It works both locally and on Azure for me. It looks like openhtmltopdf has no dependency on libwkhtmltox.